# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. - Pinterest oauth implementation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, cors, pinterest

I am implementing oauth for pinterest and able to get the access code, but when I am trying to do a `GET /v1/me/` I am getting this error in chrome console -

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me?oauth_token=XXXXX&v=20121125. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

In general I know its related to headers setting in server end for enabling CORS, but I want to know specifically how can I make it working for pinterest.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have not whitelisted your URL (https://localhost:3000) in the pinterest developers section where it asks you to specify redirect url.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try jsonp method to do a cors request in angualrjs.

$http.jsonp('https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me?oauth_token=XXXXX&v=20121125&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')

Comment: with this you will need to use a jsonp callback

Comment: Yes, a callback is added, thanks for your reminding.